# Applying Homography transformation in python without using opencv

Tags: image, image-processing, scikit-image, homography

Given an input image and the homography matrix, I want to get an output image after the transformation.

This is the built-in function in ndimage:

```py
im = np.array(Image.open('lena.jpg').convert('L'))

H = np.array([[1.4,0.05,-100],[0.05,1.5,-100],[0,0,1]])

im2 = ndimage.affine_transform(im, H[:2,:2], (H[0,2], H[1, 2]))

imshow(im)
imshow(im2)
```

For the original image I see this:

[image]

For im2 after ndimage transformation I see this:

[image]

Now I want to write a code only using python and numpy library to do this homography myself. This is the code I wrote:

```py
left, up = 0, 0
right, down = im.shape[1], im.shape[0]

# define the homography operation

def get_point_coor(x, y, H):
    input = np.array(([x], [y], [1]))
    output = np.dot(H, input)
    return int(output[0]), int(output[1])

# after transformation the image size might be different from the original one, 
# we need to find the new size
height_max = max(get_point_coor(left, up, H)[0], get_point_coor(left, down, H)[0], get_point_coor(right, up, H)[0], get_point_coor(right, up, H)[0])
width_max = max(get_point_coor(left, up, H)[1], get_point_coor(left, down, H)[1], get_point_coor(right, up, H)[1], get_point_coor(right, up, H)[1])
height_min = min(get_point_coor(left, up, H)[0], get_point_coor(left, down, H)[0], get_point_coor(right, up, H)[0], get_point_coor(right, up, H)[0])
width_min = min(get_point_coor(left, up, H)[1], get_point_coor(left, down, H)[1], get_point_coor(right, up, H)[1], get_point_coor(right, up, H)[1])

# can ignore this 50 now. The new_height without 50 should be able to be the new boundary
# , but somehow it is not, so I add a random big number (50) for ploting.
new_height = abs(height_max) + abs(height_min)+50
new_width = abs(width_max) + abs(width_min)+50

new_image = np.zeros((new_height, new_width))



# start the main
for row in range(im.shape[0]):
    for col in range(im.shape[1]):
        new_row, new_col = get_point_coor(row, col, H)

        new_col += abs(width_min)
        new_row += abs(height_min)
        
        new_image[new_row, new_col] = im[row][col]

imshow(new_image)
```

The result I get is this:

[image]

The direction, color, and size all look very different from the ndimage one. What is the correct way to implement this homography?

Comment: invert the homography. then, for every *result pixel position*, stick it in the inverted matrix (if it's a true homography and not just affine, you also need to divide by the "w" coordinate so you get `(?, ?, 1)`), and you get the pixel position in the *source* where you need to sample. -- what you do is wrong. you can't *push* pixels around. that'll leave gaps and other nasty artefacts.

Comment: what you see in your images is that `scipy.ndimage.affine_transform` *doesn't* invert the matrix. it assumes that the matrix is already inverted (i.e. backwards). always read the documentation of what you're using, and work on understanding it all: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.affine_transform.html

Comment: also, your min/max stuff there removes the translation component of the matrix in the result, so you don't get to see its effect...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, but you are making a beginner's mistake: if you scan the source image and copy the pixels to the destination at transformed coordinates, you will get poor results: either the points will be too dense and colliding with each other, or too sparse and leave holes.

The right thing to do is to scan the destination and get the source coordinate using the *inverse* transformation.

As the source coordinates will not be integer in general, you can round them, or for better quality use bilinear or bicubic interpolation between the source pixels.

A second difficulty appears: as the destination domain is a general quadrilateral, you should only paint the inside pixels, and that takes a raster scan conversion of the outline. Alternatively, you can fill the bounding box of this quadrilateral and assign the background color when the source pixel is out of the bounds.